# CC12 Contactor is Confusing

Tags: power, relay, contactor

I am attempting to use [this relay](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/carlo-gavazzi-inc/CC12SA120/1864-1289-ND/7696561), the CC12, to turn the 120VAC power to a motor/motor controller on and off using a 24VDC signal (These voltages are specified in the [datasheet](https://www.gavazzionline.com/pdf/ContactorBrochureCCseries.pdf).), and I've gotten rather lost as to which connectors to plug into what.

I know that the A1 and A2 input and output are the main power terminals, but other than that, I'm stuck. How would I achieve the result I have described?

I am providing a picture of the contactor here to give more context:

[image: Contactor Top]
(The A1 and A2 inputs and outputs are on the sides, not shown in the picture.)

EDIT: I realized that a diagram I had included as part of my question didn't actually apply to the screw-terminal version of the contactor (which I have).

Comment: Is your motor a 3 phase or only single phase?

Comment: The diagram is confusing but I would say that you can ignore the diagram and connect the 3 phases to the R, S and T terminals and the motor to U, V and W.

Comment: Also, from what I see here https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/carlo-gavazzi-inc/CC12SA120/1864-1289-ND/7696561 the coil voltage is 120VAC So it will be impossible to turn it ON via 24VDC

Comment: L1/L2/L3 is the 3 phase supply and U/V/W to the 3 phase motor. A1 and A2 to supply for the coil to TURN-ON or TURN-OFF the contractor

Comment: The motor controller is single-phase

Comment: The diagram you had in your initial edit looks like 2 contactors wired up as a reversing function - Phases L1 & L3 get swapped over and the aux contactor terminals prevent both contactors from being turned on simultaneously (which would short L1 & L3 - big bang).

Comment: [This](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/carlo-gavazzi-inc/CC12SA24/CC12SA24-ND/8542901) is the version with a 24V coil, not the one you linked to.

Comment: The 'datasheet' you link to is a brochure for the entire series. There are 24v, 120V and 240V coil versions.

Comment: It seems I've ordered the wrong part then. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Can you wire the full contactor model type that you have bought?

Comment: @brhans this is 24AC coil version not DC

Comment: The DigiKey page you linked is for a 120 VAC coil version.

Comment: @G36 - who said anything about DC?

Comment: @brhans - the OP said "24 VDC" in his question.

Comment: This is 24VDC version CC12SD24  https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=cc12sd24

Comment: @G36 That last version with 24VDC is for the coil voltage, not the on/off voltage. My goal was to have a 120VAC relay turned on/off by 24VDC. I am now not sure if there is any model of this contactor that satisfies those requirements.

Comment: It would actually be better for my project to find a 120VAC relay that can be switched on/off by 3.3VDC, so I will now look for something like that.

Comment: The contactor contacts can switch 120 VAC.  The coil is the part of the contactor that causes the contacts to switch.  If you apply 24 VDC to the coil, the contacts will close (or turn on) - remove that power, and they will open (turn off).

Comment: @Blapor I see. So you can use your contactor then. Simple use L1 terminal to hot-wire and U terminal to your motor controller. And A1 - A2 terminals to turn on/off the contactor via relay.

Comment: You will not find any such thing in a contactor. 24VDC coil voltage is fine. It can switch any voltage on the 3 main contacts up to 600VAC. 120VAC is less than 600VAC. I don't see the aux contact rating. You can test the one you have with an ohmmeter and manually pressing the orange bit to simulate the coil (no mains voltage applied, obviously). Each of T1, 2, 3 should close to L1, 2, 3.

Comment: @G36 The digikey link in the original question is the model I actually have, so I don't think I can use it, as described in the answer by CoreyF (Unless that is incorrect?)

Comment: @Blapor But you can use an additional 24VDC coil relay with 120VAC  or higher contact rating.

Comment: It's possible the 120VAC coil will work from 24DC but it would need to be tested. It might not pull in well enough or it might overheat. If it pulls in around 15V-17VDC it's probably okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a few clarifications, the contactor you posted is the CC12SA120, the A120 in that part number indicates a coil operated by 120VAC. So if this particular contactor pictured has a 24VDC coil, then the part should be the [CC12SD24](https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=CC12SD24).

If you have 24VDC control and the contactor you are trying to connect is the 120VAC coil version then you would have to find a way to change your control voltage (not commenting on because I do not know your control setup), or purchase the correct contactor.

This contactor allows for a 3-phase connection but because of your reply in comment that this application is a single-phase 120VAC motor, you only need to use one set of terminals. I would suggest connecting your supply to L1 and the motor to T1.

Comment: Thanks for the well-explained answer! I am unable to change the controls to use 120VAC, but I will likely attempt to order a contactor that is more suited to my needs.

Comment: You said I should connect to L1 (in from power outlet) and T1 (out to motor), but there are two power wires, as AC power tends to have, so through which terminal set do I put the second wire?

Comment: Also, where would the activation/deactivation signal go?

Comment: Neutral and ground always remain connected; you are only connecting/disconnecting the hot wire with the contactor. A1 and A2 are the coil terminals, which is where you connect the control signal. For the contactor your linked, the control terminals take 120VAC to close the contacts.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think that comment alone gave me a much better understanding of how this works